# vertical alignment in textarea

Tags: css, textarea, vertical-alignment

I have a textarea of 4 rows and 20 columns. I want the cursor to start at the bottom left. When I write something to the textarea, the text will go up. Is there any css code I can write for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified solution that will work if the number of rows is static. The solution gives the impression of having a textarea element while hiding the input fields (removed the border around each text input).

```
    <head>
        <script>    
            function goUpOneRow( e, row ){
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    document.getElementById( row ).focus();
                }               
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            #inputarea {
                border:1px solid #ccc;
                width:300px;
                height:150px;
            }

            #inputarea input {
                width:100%;
                height:25%;
                font-size:18px;
                border: 0;
                outline-width: 0;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

<body>
    <div id="inputarea">
      <div><input id="row1" type="text"> </div>
      <div><input id="row2" type="text" onKeyPress="goUpOneRow( event, 'row1' );"> </div>
      <div><input id="row3" type="text" onKeyPress="goUpOneRow( event, 'row2' );"> </div>
      <div><input id="row4" type="text" autofocus onKeyPress="goUpOneRow( event, 'row3' );"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
```